# Recursive RealmList. Will such schema work?

Tags: android, list, oop, realm, realm-list

Is this correct approach in creating of Realm schema?

```
public class Merchandise extends RealmObject {
    private long id;
    private String name;
}

public class Cluster extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
}


Cluster assortment = new Cluster;
assortment.setName("Assortment");
assortment.setList(new RealmList<Cluster> assortment_list);
// there are "meat", "poultry", "milk_products" etc. in this RL

Cluster milk_products = new Cluster;
milk_products.setName("Milk products");
milk_products.setList(new RealmList<Cluster> milk_products_list); 
// there are "cottage_cheeses", "milk_desserts" etc. in this RL

Cluster milk_desserts = new Cluster;
milk_desserts.setName("Milk desserts");
milk_desserts.setList(new RealmList<Cluster> milk_desserts_list);
// there are "cottage_cheese_casseroles", "panna_cottas" etc. in this RL

Cluster panna_cottas = new Cluster;
panna_cottas.setName("Panna-cotta");
panna_cottas.setList(new RealmList<Merchandise> panna_cottas_list); 
// various kinds of panna-cotta in this RL
```

There are `MerchandiseRecyclerView` (main data here) and `ClusterRecyclerView` (using to filter displaying data in MRV).

I want to show all Merchandise objects in MRV when querying Realm for "assortment_list", and for example show only products from milk querying for "milk_products_list".

Will this recursive relationships work?

Comment: I don't think I understand what exactly your model class looks like.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I rewrote the question